# Will an update to Chrubuntu damage Chrome OS?

Tags: kernel, updates, xubuntu, chromeos, chrubuntu

I am running Chrome OS 40 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Chromebook 2. I was wondering if updating to Ubuntu 14.04 will update my kernel and break Chrome OS. I've almost updated before, but then I stopped myself after it said something about "kernel updates". I know Chrome OS uses the Linux kernel, but I don't know if it uses the latest version. I really want to install the latest Ubuntu, but I also don't want to damage Chrome OS. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updating Chrubuntu will not harm the ChromeOS

### (Updating the kernel from a Crouton based install will mess everything up)

Chrubuntu installs Ubuntu in a separate partition, much like a dual-boot setup that has Windows and Ubuntu in different partitions. So, updating Ubuntu won't do anything to the ChromeOS and vice versa.

However, the Chrubuntu script tweaks the standard Ubuntu install to work with the Chromebook/Chromebox hardware. For example, touchpad of the Acer C720 Chromebook is not recognized in the default Ubuntu installation. The Chrubuntu script fixes that. A kernel update or an upgrade to 14.04 will change the Ubuntu kernel (but not the ChromeOS kernel in a different partition). **This will undo the tweaks** made by the Chrubuntu installation script. I don't know how this will affect Toshiba Chromebook 2.

*Note:* **This answer does not apply to Crouton based installation.** Crouton uses the ChromeOS kernel, and is not a real Ubuntu installation. Any attempt to update the ChromeOS kernel with an Ubuntu kernel will probably break both the Crouton as well as the ChromeOS installations.

Hope this helps

Comment: Shoot. I'm running a crouton-based installation. Thanks for the tip, thuough.

Comment: I found [this how-to to upgrade Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Upgrade-chroot-release) using Google search. I have no experience with it. Best of luck.